# What's the meaning of"of" in the sentence ".... the thief of joy"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> Comparison is the thief **of** joy.

I found a relevant definition on dictionary.I want to be assured of it.(If it's actually the relevant definition )

The definition(of "of")is:—
***used after a noun describing an action to show either who did the action or who it happened to***

I'm unsure whether this is the meaning here because the word "thief" refers to a person, not action.

Comment: Hi. Where did you find this expression? Do you have a quote you can link to? It's meaning likely depends on context which you haven't provided.  At first sight, it seems to be an example of figurative language, a metaphor. It's not literal. It means something like:  Comparison takes away ones joy. - i.e. form of personification where "comparison" is being likened to a thief who steals one's joy.

Comment: @BillyKerr I want to know only the meaning of the Preposition "of". There is no context. This is a simple saying.

Comment: I've already told you its literal meaning.  A thief is a person who steals:  the thief of joy = the thief who steals joy.

Comment: @BillyKerr, so the definition I have give is relevant?

Comment: Sure. It's similar to: a collector of stamps = a person who collects stamps.  A doctor of medicine = a person who practices medicine.  A curator of art = a person who curates art.  A man of few words = a man who speaks few words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no doubt that the "of" in "*love of nature*" is the same as the "of" in "*love**r** of nature*", which is a *person* who loves nature.

The same goes for "*theft of joy*" and "***thief** of joy*".

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of)'s definition is an improvement on the one you found because it allows "thief" to go before "of" with this meaning:

> **of** *preposition*
> **9 a —** used as a function word to indicate the object of an action denoted or implied by the preceding noun
> *love of nature*

This definition says, "*...an action denoted **or implied** by the preceding noun*", and the action of "theft" is certainly implied by the noun "thief".

Comment: Ok, Thanks, but other dictionaries have not included this small details, can You say why?

Comment: Some dictionaries are simply better than others, and this is an example of one dictionary having a superior definition to another. I always go to M-W first, and even they aren't quite perfect. So sometimes I also check [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/of?q=of) (see definition 9) and [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/of) (see definition 11)